# Como configurar puertos COM & LPT desde PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Como configurar los parámetros que presenta esta imagen desde PowerShell?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: your question is in English, I suggest you [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Encontré un ejemploe en https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/writing-and-reading-info-from-serial-ports/  $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,9600,None,8,one  Le ayuda?

Comment: Ya lo habia visto pero desafortunamente no.